# "Hacking" pointers and c++ like memory management into Java

Tags: java, memory-management

I've had this idea in my head recently for being able to have a pointer like system in Java. The general idea is to have a static class called Memory. Whenever in a program, you want to create an object, instead of declaring it as a private field, instead create an integer. This functions as the handle/pointer for the object. In order to create the object, you call `int ptr = Memory.create(new Object());`. The memory class stores the object in the first empty slot of a static array, which it in return returns the index of. In order to deallocate the memory, simply call `Memory.destroy(ptr);` the memory class would then set that index of the array to null, removing it from memory.

I'm almost certain approaches like this have in the past been thought of for circumventing the gc problems in java, however I don't think I've ever heard or seen it be used, for which I assume there is a significant reason. So my question is: What are the advantages and disadvantages of this idea, and why is it not used?

EDIT: Thank you for the responses. Sorry that this idea has been received so negatively (lots of downvotes), I was more or less curious about why it wouldn't work (there was no doubt in my mind that it didn't, I was just curious as to the reasoning). I guess I should have checked that setting an object to null would delete an object/speed up the gc before posting here. From previous experience, I wrongfully assumed it did. Sorry all.

Comment: Why take that trouble if there is a built-in garbage collector? What problems would it solve?

Comment: This has no advantage in terms of memory management. `The memory class stores the object in the first empty slot of a static array` you're still using an array of Objects which internally are references to the heap, hence still garbage collection. and you have problems if your array isn't large enough! This would only add additional overhead without any benefit

Comment: @Marvin when siting evidence for usage of c++ over java, most programmers say that the garbage collector in java is what slows down java programs. The concept I've outlined would simplify the gc's job significantly and allow manual memory deallocation (although in a hacky indirect way, which is what im concerned about)

Comment: The benefits of C-style memory management don't come only from the absence of garbage collection, but from benefits gained from organizing memory how you want (better use of locality and smarter reuse of resources). in java, you *can not do this* there's no way around it, no "hacking" can give you these benefits

Comment: No, it wouldn't simplify the gc's job.

Comment: @vu1p3n0x sorry for not fully explaining how (I thought) this would work. I mean this more from the perspective of freeing up cpu time by simplifying the gc's job, not from memory conservation. Tobias below explains why even that would not work.

Comment: Besides, while talking about the advantages of C++, also consider it's disadvantages (memory leaks, double free, invalid pointers...)

Comment: @TobiasWeimer right, I understand now why setting and object to null doesn't function the way I thought it did. Thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement another language in Java, but you cannot get the other language to perform as it would if Java was not present.

C++ does not run on top of a virtual machine, so when you `free` memory, it is actually released in C++.  Java does not expose low level memory handling to the application, so any thing that you do will be a simulation on top of the actual semantics of the memory handling done by the virtual machine.

---- Now that the facts are taken care of... it's time for opinion ----

Java's memory handling was designed specifically to remove a few issues present in C++ programs.  If one comes from a C++ background, they might not like the different environment.  However, attempting to restore those problems would not garner a lot of constructive help.

Java does have references, which are effectively identical to pointers with the one difference that pointer math cannot be performed on a reference.  Thus one can have an array of references (which is typically done by having an array of classes), and walk between the references by using array indexing, but cannot hold only one reference and "increment" it by the `++` operator.

If you attempt to progress down this path, remember that Java also has a pluggable garbage collector, and that allocation is sometimes not done "one object at a time" but rather "a handful of objects at a time" to speed up allocation of multiple objects of the same kind.

---- A practical example ----

Within a block of code

```
public int doIt() {
   String foo = "hello";
   return 5;
}
```

the Object `String foo` isn't required to be allocated on the heap.  In this block of code

```
public int doIt() {
   Customer bob = new Customer("bob");
   bob.setAge(32);
   return 5;
}
```

The `Customer` object `bob` is not required to be allocated on the heap.

In short, Java has lots of approaches to memory management.  Before you implement the C++ way within Java, you need to become aware of Java's memory management because you really don't have the option of replacing memory management within Java, meaning you'll encounter it either way.

---- A final note ----

If you really want this, I suggest you drop through to C++ using JNI.  Stuff allocated in JNI must be freed in that layer, and doesn't participate in Java's heap / stack management policies.

Answer (score 2):

Setting an array index to null doesn't **immediately** remove it from the **memory**. You still have to wait for the GC. It rather creates more leaks if the array index isn't properly removed. There is really no way to circumvent the GC.

Comment: Thank you! That makes a lot of sense.